# Overriding WebAPI controller naming convention doesn't work

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am having difficulties to understand how WebAPI routing is working. This is what my controller looks like:

```
[RoutePrefix("order-mgmt")]
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("execute")]
    public HttpResponse ExecOrder(string clordid)
    {
        // ...
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("reject")]
    public HttpResponse RejectOrder(string clordid)
    {
        // ...
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

And this is my `Startup` class and configuration

```
public class Startup 
{ 
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) 
    { 
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration(); 

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            name: "ActionApi", 
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
        ); 

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config); 
    } 
}
```

I was expecting that I am able to reach `public HttpResponseMessage ExecOrder(string clordid)` via `http://localhost:port/api/order-mgmt/execute?clordid=<clordidstring>`.

This however doesn't work. The controller is still only reachable via `api/order/execute`. I really don't get what I am doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess no custom match is found (and so the fallback to standard routing) as you have /api/ within the url.  Can you try either  http://localhost:port/order-mgmt/execute?clordid=<clordidstring> or update your routeprefix to RoutePrefix("api/order-mgmt")

Comment: Thank you, stupid me... Also I removed the configuration part about convention-based routing, so only `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` is in place and added `RoutePrefix("api/order-mgmt")` instead of `RoutePrefix("order-mgmt")` as you suggested and everything is fine...

Answer (score 1):

try removing [RoutePrefix("order-mgmt")]

then do it like this

```
[Route("api/order-mgmt/execute/{clordid}")]
public HttpResponse ExecOrder(string clordid)

// then you can reach it in this route
// api/order-mgmt/execute/YOUR_STRING
```